# C# Searching PDFs

Tags: c#, pdf, search

I'm using `iTextSharp` to get the content out of a pdf. I want to allow the user to search for PDFs, much like they do on any search engine. The search should return the most relevant results. I have written a library that performs the TF-IDF algorithm on the documents to return relevant results. While this works,  I feel like I may be reinventing the wheel.

This user should be able to search well over 50,000 PDFs. So there's alot of them. I don't want to store the full content of the PDF in my database as I feel that would be SUPER expensive. To mitigate this,  I've written my library so that it will accept a frequency distribution when calculating TF-IDF. This allows me to read the PDF when it's added to the system instead of every time a search is performed.

Do libraries exist that already do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene.NET will do what you need.

And there are commercial ones like our 'SearchUnit'